# Plot contour map of magnetic intensities over World Map, but I get a bad input error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, magpylib

Using magpylib I can obtain these magnetic intensities (anywhere, at any latitude and longitude) with function getB( sources, observers ). What I want to do is plot a contour map using these values over a world map, however I have a feeling that the getB() function can't work with meshgrids (or maybe I can't).
I also get a bad input error:
`` Input parameter `pixel` must be array_like (list, tuple, ndarray) with shape (n1, n2, ..., 3). Instead received array_like with shape (3, 50, 50). ``

This is my code:

````
import magpylib as magpy
import numpy as np
from magpylib import Collection
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
import time

R = 6371000000

mx = -0.40e27  # in mT mm3 
my =  -2.39e27
mz = -7.04e27

rx = -0.01e9 # in mm
ry = -0.28e9
rz = 0.40e9

x1 = magpy.misc.Dipole((mx, my, mz), (rx, ry, rz))

xlist = np.linspace( -180, 180) # longitudine
ylist = np.linspace( -90, 90) # latitudine
X, Y = np.meshgrid( xlist, ylist )

x = R * np.cos( np.deg2rad( Y ) ) * np.cos( np.deg2rad( X ) )
y = R * np.cos( np.deg2rad( Y ) ) * np.sin( np.deg2rad( X ) )
z = R * np.sin( np.deg2rad( Y ) )

B = x1.getB((x, y, z))

b_fin = 0
for i in range(0, 3):
    b_fin += B[i]**2
b_fin = np.sqrt( b_fin )
b_fin *= 1000
Z = b_fin

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,5))
left, bottom, width, height = 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8
ax = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height]) 


cp = ax.contour(X, Y, Z)
ax.clabel(cp, inline=True, fontsize=10)
ax.set_title('Contour Plot')
ax.set_xlabel('longitude (o)')
ax.set_ylabel('latitude (o)')
plt.show()```

I'd be very grateful if any of you have any suggestions.
````

Answer (score 1):

just stumbled on this question today... probably a bit late^^

As the error message states, the shape of your observers input must be an array with `shape (n1, n2, ..., 3)`. Which means the last dimension must be of length 3. In your example, the shape is (3,50,50), so the first dimension is of length 3 but not the last one. You'll need to transpose the input, or swap axes (1,2) or (0,2).

for example

```py
import magpylib as magpy
import numpy as np
from magpylib import Collection
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
import time

R = 6371000000
##
mx = -0.40e27  # in mT mm3 
my =  -2.39e27
mz = -7.04e27

rx = -0.01e9 # in mm
ry = -0.28e9
rz = 0.40e9

x1 = magpy.misc.Dipole((mx, my, mz), (rx, ry, rz))

xlist = np.linspace( -180, 180) # longitudine
ylist = np.linspace( -90, 90) # latitudine
X, Y = np.meshgrid( xlist, ylist )

x = R * np.cos( np.deg2rad( Y ) ) * np.cos( np.deg2rad( X ) )
y = R * np.cos( np.deg2rad( Y ) ) * np.sin( np.deg2rad( X ) )
z = R * np.sin( np.deg2rad( Y ) )

#transpose points from shape (3, 50,50) to (50,50,3)
pts = np.array((x, y, z)).T

B = x1.getB(pts).T
#transpose result back to (3, 50,50) shape

b_fin = 0
for i in range(0, 3):
    b_fin += B[i]**2
b_fin = np.sqrt( b_fin )
b_fin *= 1000
Z = b_fin

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,5))
left, bottom, width, height = 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8
ax = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height]) 


cp = ax.contour(X, Y, Z)
ax.clabel(cp, inline=True, fontsize=10)
ax.set_title('Contour Plot')
ax.set_xlabel('longitude (o)')
ax.set_ylabel('latitude (o)')
plt.show()
```

[countourplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu39V.png)